# When is a PL function linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-polytopes, pl-manifolds

We have a simplicial decomposition of a $n$-dimensional disk $D_n$ an a PL function $\mu$ on the decomposition. For each set of vertices $v_1,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1}$, so that both $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_n$ and $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_{n+1}$ are simplices of the disk, we know the values $\alpha_i$ for which the relation
$\alpha_1\mu(v_1)+\dots+\alpha_{n+1}\mu(v_{n+1})=0$ holds.

Is it possible to determine from the $\alpha_i$'s if $\mu$ is the restriction of a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ for some linear embedding $D_n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?
Or in general, is it possible to determine it by some "local information" from the PL function?

Comment: What is PL? Please edit the question.

Comment: Surely it means piecewise linear?